# Tabbed Multipage Ajaxified Forms

Tags: forms, ajax, navigation

I need a way to create a form with tabbed navigation at the top, "save and next"/"save and back" navigation at the bottom, and saving the data for an individual page using ajax, with the following business rules:

-A user may access and work in any part of the form at any time.

-Individual pages can be saved, even if nothing in the rest of the form is filled out.

-Changes in any page result in a "exit without saving? prompt", implemented as a separate module (but which can detect switching between tabs).

I have attempted to do this using fieldgroups: Root is a horizontal tab group, which has a single child in the form of a multipage group, which has 1 tab item child for each page, which in turn each have 1 multipage child, in which I place the forms. The hirarchy looks like this:

Horizontal Tab Group->Multipage Group->Tab Item->Multipage

This doesn't work; apparently the fieldgroups module doesn't let groups search beyond a single level. If they could search beyond that, this may have worked fine and I could have applied the ajaxified multipage fieldgroups module.

What is the best way to go about accomplishing this in D7?

Comment: have u looked into ctools?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Multipage jumplist](https://www.drupal.org/project/multipage_jumplist) module which provides a block that allows you to access all multipages.

To apply the ajaxified multipage fieldgroups, use: [Field Group Ajaxified Multipage](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_ajaxified_multipage) module which allows you to enable AJAX for multipage groups
It also provides developers with special variables attached to form array regarding page status to allow them further customize the form (e.g. form_alter) depending on active page (in this case saving your pages).